# Linear Objective function - nonlinear constraints different results for different initial values

Tags: matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have an optimization problem.
My objective function is a linear function which is:

```
f=h(1)+h(2)+h(3)+h(4)+h(5)
```

where `h(i)=t(i+1)-t(i)`

My constraints are non-linear:

`v_{ji}-v_{max,j}<=0`   and `a_{ji}-a_{max,j}<=0`

where

```
for m=1:6
for i=2:4
v_{ji}=abs(((ddq(m,i+1)*(t(i+1)-time(j))^2)/(2*h(i)))+((ddq(m,(i+3))*(time(j)-t(i))^2)/h(i))+((path(m,i+1)/h(i))-(h(i)*ddq(m,(i+3)))/6)-((path(m,i)/h(i))-(h(i)*(ddq(m,i+1))/6)))-v_{max,j};
end
end
```

and

```
for m=1:6
    for i=2:4
    a_{ji}=abs(((ddq(m,(i+2))/h(i))*(time(j)-t(i)))-((ddq(m,i+1)/h(i))*(time(j)-t(i+1))))-a_max(j);
    end
    end
```

time(j) is a random value between t(i) and t(i+1). I used fmincon function to obtain the optimized `h` values where I set the options as:

```
 options=optimset('Algorithm','sqp','Display','iter','DiffMinChange',1e-6,'DiffMaxChange',1e-1,'TolFun',1e-10,'TolX',1e-16,'MaxFunEvals',10000,'MaxIter',250);
```

When I run the code I got different results for different initial values such as:

```
for h_0=[1 1 1 1 1], h=[0.052 0.087 0.104 0.007 0.002]
for h_0=[0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5], h=[0.020 0.059 0.106 0.011 0.003]  
for h_0=[0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1], h=[0.017 0.05 0.107 0.017 0.042]
```

I also tried to solve the same problem with `active-set` and `interior-point` algorithms and the values obtained from `active set`  is

```
for h_0=[0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1], h=[0.094 0.106 0.1 0.1 0.1]
```

and it didn't work for different values.

interior-point algorithm also didn't work and I couldn't get any results.

My questions are:
1. Why did I get different results for each different initial value?
2. Why didn't other algorithms work for this question?
3. If I had to change algorithm which one is the best for this problem and why?

Comment: It looks like you have multiple local optima and starting from different initial points the algorithm converges to different optima. Can you try a global optimization technique?

Comment: like which algorithm? Could you send me a link for it?